# Why the property "perspective" doesn't work for me?

Tags: html, css, webkit, transform

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    border: 10px solid yellow;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600);
    transform: perspective(600);
}
```

This doesn't work, it always display a red square... I don't understand why.
I use Chrome 23

Comment: You might want to try making different sides different colors. A totally monochromatic cube just looks like a square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The perspective needs to be combined with another transform to be of any use. Have a look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/TD8Hr/

html:

```
<div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div { padding: 50px; }

div > div {
                width: 50px; 
               height: 50px; 
           background: red;
               border: 10px solid yellow;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600) rotateY(120deg);
       -moz-transform: perspective(600) rotateY(120deg);
            transform: perspective(600) rotateY(120deg);
                    }
```

Comment: @Steffi - no worries. You could expand on this and create something like http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php